# How would I implement ADB commands into my Swift 5 MacOS app?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, adb, swift5

I'm trying to make a MacOS app that pushes a .txt and .obb file to an Android device, installs an APK to that Android device, then runs a few commands granting permissions. Problem is, I have no clue where to start. I researched how to implement shell commands but the explanations provided weren't making sense.

How would I go about implementing ADB commands in Swift 5? In addition to that, can I bundle the platform-tools in the app so that the user doesn't have to have the Android SDK installed?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: I have found a function that looks like it should work, and it produces an actual result which is nice. Here's what it says:

```
func shell(command: String) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "~/Downloads/PavlovVR_OpenAlpha_BuildNum_22/platform-tools/adb"
    task.arguments = ["args"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

This function should be pointing to the adb executable, allowing me to run adb commands from the function like this:

```
shell(command: "adb devices")
```

When I try to run it it outputs:

```
adb: unknown command args
```

What should I put in task.arguments in order to make the command go through?

Comment: `task.arguments = ["args"]` does `adb args`. Try `task.arguments = [command]` and `shell(command: "devices")`. See [arguments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1408983-arguments)

Comment: Thank you for the fix, but now I have a different issue. I can't run commands more than one word. "devices" works fine. "install /path/to/file" will not work, says unknown command. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: See [arguments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1408983-arguments). "An array of NSString objects that supplies the arguments to the task.". Each argument is a string: `["install", "/path/to/file"]`.

Comment: Oh wow that worked! Thank you very much for the help, I was stuck on this for a while.